# About Crashlytics Ndk

Tags: android-ndk, crashlytics

I want to use Crashlytics in my cocos project. I set up Crashlytics in my project step by step. But I can not get correct crash info. This is logcat stack info:

```
I/DEBUG   ( 6752): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #01  pc 008df4fc  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.crashAndroid-2/libcocos2dlua.so (AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground()+68)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #02  pc 008f3ac0  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.crashAndroid-2/libcocos2dlua.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeOnPause+108)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #03  pc 0001e610  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #04  pc 0004e00d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+500)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #05  pc 000503d5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+200)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #06  pc 000279e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #07  pc 0002b934  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #08  pc 000613ed  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #09  pc 00061417  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #10  pc 00055a71  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #11  pc 0000e058  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752): 
I/DEBUG   ( 6752): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeeba0  130cad26  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeeba4  5f1a5e3b  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.crashAndroid-2/libcocos2dlua.so (operator delete(void*)+6)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeeba8  130cad26  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebac  5ecd5820  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.crashAndroid-2/libcocos2dlua.so (cocos2d::Node::~Node()+32)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebb0  5f9eef28  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebb8  5faeebdc  [stack:6720]
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebbc  5ee0d6d0  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.crashAndroid-2/libcocos2dlua.so (cocos2d::Ref::release()+504)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebc0  5f4492d0  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.crashAndroid-2/libcocos2dlua.so
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebc4  0000009e  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebcc  62b005c8  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebd0  5f6819c0  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.crashAndroid-2/libcocos2dlua.so
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebd4  60fd9678  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebe8  5f6819c0  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.crashAndroid-2/libcocos2dlua.so
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebec  62b005c8  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebf0  5faeec44  [stack:6720]
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebf4  5e18dac4  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.crashAndroid-2/libcocos2dlua.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeOnPause+112)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):     #02  5faeebf8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeebfc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeec18  62b02848  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeec1c  400e7c2c  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+608)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeec20  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeec24  400faf1c  /system/lib/libc.so (sprintf+104)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeec28  5faeeca0  [stack:6720]
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeec2c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeec30  4162f5e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          5faeec34  130cad26  
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   ( 6752):
```

But in the dashboard, I just get little crash info. this is dashboard`s info:

```
Crashed: Thread
0  (Missing)                      0x10000000000000000 (Missing)
1  libcocos2dlua.so               0x5e18dac2 Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeOnPause (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer.cpp:23)
2  (Missing)                      0x416fca03 (Missing)
12 (Missing)                      0x5d841433 (Missing)
13 libcocos2dlua.so               0x5e18da52 Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeRender (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer.cpp:19)
14 libdvm.so                      0x40f305a5 (Missing)
15 libc.so                        0x400ef66c (Missing)
```

I worked on it three days,and do not find the question where it is.Any response will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I read the offical document, send the symbol file. But it also do not work corrently. But I changed my source codes just now, it worked corrently.So I think if you used it do not worked, maybe the crash info is same as before. it do not get new crash info to the dashboard. All of those, It's just my personal opinion. And thanks Mike Bonnell, He gave me some hints,it is helpfully.